# zendframewok form input not working proper on server

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am using zend framework 1.12
There is one text area in form.
I write below html in this text area  name='content'

```
<p>
<img width="100" height="63" alt="" src="/public/images/image/roses-bush-wallpaper-dsc03633.jpg" />
</p>
```

After form submit I get below in $_POST['content]

```
<p>
<img width="\&quot;100\&quot;" height="\&quot;63\&quot;" alt="\&quot;\&quot;" src="\&quot;/public/images/image/roses-bush-wallpaper-dsc03633.jpg\&quot;" />
</p>
```

this html encode is not require to me.

Main problem is that I am facing problem on server only in my localhost it works fine. In localhost I get the same in post as I input in textarea.

Below is the zenform element

```
$content = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('content');
$content->setLabel('content')
    ->setAttrib('rows', 12)
    ->setAttrib('cols', 40)
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
     ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

magic_quotes_gpc is enabled on your server
You can try any one from following to disable it.

1. You can add in htaccess cile

   php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
2. create a php.ini file at your root directory.
   Add this content to the file and save

   magic_quotes_gpc = Off
   magic_quotes_runtime = Off
   magic_quotes_sybase = Off

   Edit your .htaccess file and add this line at the top and save the file

   SetEnv PHPRC /home/youruser/public_html/php.ini
3. add below function at top of your php file

   ini_set( 'magic_quotes_gpc', 0 );
4. Without disabling magic code from php configuration you can modify your code as below

   $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

Answer (score 0):

You have "magic-quotes-gpc= on" on your server. Please check following page to see how to disable it:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php